# How to use Tensorflow's batch_sequences_with_states utility

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to build a generative RNN using Tensorflow. I have a preprocessed dataset which is a list of `sequence_length x 2048 x 2` numpy arrays. The sequences have different lengths. I have been looking through examples and documentation but I really couldn't understand, for example, what `key` is, or how I should create the `input_sequences` dictionary, etc.

So how should one format a list of numpy arrays, each of which represent a sequence of rank n (2 in this case) tensors, in order to be able to use this `batch_sequences_with_states` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Toy Implementations**

I tried this and I will be glad to share my findings with you. It is a toy example. I attempted to create an example that works and observe how the output varies. In particular I used a case study of lstm. For you, you can define a conv net. Feel free to add more input and adjust as usual and follow the doc.
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.training/splitting_sequence_inputs_into_minibatches_with_state_saving#batch_sequences_with_states
There are other more subtle examples I tried but I keep this simple version to show how the operation can be useful. In particular add more elements to the dictionaries (input sequence and context sequence) and observe the changes.

**Two Approaches**

Basically I will use two approaches:

1. tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states
2. tf.train.batch( )

I will start with the first one because it will directly helpful then I will show how to solve similar problem with train.batch.

I will basically be generate toy  numpy arrays and tensors and use it for testing the operations

```
import tensorflow as tf
batch_size = 32
num_unroll = 20
num_enqueue_threads = 20
lstm_size = 8
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=lstm_size)


#state size
state_size = cell.state_size[0];
initial_state_values = tf.zeros((state_size,), dtype=tf.float32)

# Initial states
initial_state_values = tf.zeros((state_size,), dtype=tf.float32)
initial_states = {"lstm_state": initial_state_values}

# Key should be string
#I used x as input sequence and y as input context. So that the
# keys should be 2.
key = ["1","2"]

#Toy data for our sample
x = tf.range(0, 12, name="x")
y = tf.range(12,24,name="y")

# convert to float
#I converted to float so as not to raise type mismatch erroe
x=tf.to_float(x)
y=tf.to_float(y)

#the input sequence as dictionary
#This is needed according to the tensorflow doc

sequences = {"x": x }

#Context Input
context = {"batch1": y}

 # Train batch with sequence state
batch_new = tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states(
    input_key=key,
    input_sequences=sequences,
    input_context=context,
    initial_states=initial_states,
    num_unroll=num_unroll,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    input_length = None,
    pad = True,
    num_threads=num_enqueue_threads,
    capacity=batch_size * num_enqueue_threads * 2)

 # To test what we have got type and observe the output of
 # the following
 # In short once in ipython notebook
 # type batch_new.[press tab] to see all options
 batch_new.key
 batch_new.sequences

 #splitting of  input. This generate input per epoch
 inputs_by_time = tf.split(inputs, num_unroll)
 assert len(inputs_by_time) == num_unroll

 # Get lstm or conv net output
 lstm_output, _ = tf.contrib.rnn.static_state_saving_rnn(
           cell,
           inputs_by_time,
           state_saver=batch_new,
           state_name=("lstm_state","lstm_state"))
```

**Create Graph and Queue as Usual**

The parts with #  and * can be further adapted to suit requirement.

```
 # Create the graph, etc.
 init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

 #Create a session for running operations in the Graph.
 sess = tf.Session()

 # Initialize the variables (like the epoch counter).
 sess.run(init_op)

 # Start input enqueue threads.
 coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
 threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

 # For the part below uncomment 
 #*those comments with asterics to do other operations
 #*try:
  #*    while not coord.should_stop():
         #*Run training steps or whatever
         #*sess.run(train_op) # uncomment to run other ops


 #*except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
         #print('Done training -- epoch limit reached')
 #*finally:
      # When done, ask the threads to stop.
 coord.request_stop()
 # Wait for threads to finish.
 coord.join(threads)
 sess.close()
```

**Second Approach**

You can also use train.batch in a very interesting way:

```
import tensorflow as tf

#[0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,...]
x = tf.range(0, 11, name="x")

# A queue that outputs 0,1,2,3,..
# slice end is useful for dequeuing
slice_end = 10
# instantiate variable y 
y = tf.slice(x, [0], [slice_end], name="y")

# Reshape y
y = tf.reshape(y,[10,1])
y=tf.to_float(y, name='ToFloat')
```

**Important**
Note the use of dynamic and enqueue many with padding. Feel free to play with both options. And compare output!

```
batched_data = tf.train.batch(
    tensors=[y],
    batch_size=10,
    dynamic_pad=True,
    #enqueue_many=True,
    name="y_batch"
)

batch_size = 128 ;
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(batch_size,forget_bias=1,state_is_tuple=True)

val, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, batched_data, dtype=tf.float32)
```

**Conclusion**

The aim is to show that by simple examples we can get insight into the
details of the operations. You can adapt it to convolutional net in your case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! This really helps.