# Is there an equivalent call with "tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states" in TensorFlow 2?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am currently changing a model implemented in TF1 to TF2, originated from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/adversarial_text).

I am trying to find an equivalent call with `tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states`, yet cannot find it in TensorFlow 2.

Is there an equivalent call exist?

```py
batch = tf.contrib.training.batch_sequences_with_states(
      input_key=seq_key,
      input_sequences=sequence,
      input_context=ctx,
      input_length=tf.shape(input=sequence['token_id'])[0],
      initial_states=initial_states,
      num_unroll=unroll_steps,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      allow_small_batch=False,
      num_threads=4,
      capacity=batch_size * 10,
      make_keys_unique=True,
      make_keys_unique_seed=29392)
```

Comment: Hi @JueonParks, kindly refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42894217/14290697), it might help you. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42832829/how-to-use-tensorflows-batch-sequences-with-states-utility/42894217#42894217) as per [batch_sequences_with_states_test.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/contrib/training/python/training/batch_sequences_with_states_test.py) of Tensorflow r1.8 works :

> ```
> import tensorflow as tf
>
> #[0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,...]
> x = tf.range(0, 11, name="x")
>
> # A queue that outputs 0,1,2,3,..
> # slice end is useful for dequeuing
> slice_end = 10
> # instantiate variable y 
> y = tf.slice(x, [0], [slice_end], name="y")
>
> # Reshape y
> y = tf.reshape(y,[10,1])
> y=tf.to_float(y, name='ToFloat')
> Important Note the use of dynamic and enqueue many with padding. Feel free to play with both options. And compare output!
>
> batched_data = tf.train.batch(
>     tensors=[y],
>     batch_size=10,
>     dynamic_pad=True,
>     #enqueue_many=True,
>     name="y_batch"
> )
>
> batch_size = 128 ;
> lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(batch_size,forget_bias=1,state_is_tuple=True)
>
> val, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, batched_data, dtype=tf.float32)
> ```